# Upload multiple images

Tags: php, image, foreach, upload, explode

I try to upload some images encoded in a Base64 String separated through the char '&' e.g. base64image&base64image&base64image. But my **code**

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$Image64 = $_POST["Image64"];
$Beschreibung = $_POST["Beschreibung"];
$Image = $_POST["Image"];
$counter = 0;


$serverPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path = "$id";

$query = "UPDATE `hausaufgaben` SET `Loesung_Image` =  '$Image'  WHERE `id`= '$id';";
    if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
        $counter += 1;
        $splittedStr = explode('&',$Image64);
        foreach($splittedStr as $value){
            echo "$value";
            file_put_contents("Image.jpg",base64_decode($value)); //line 32
            rename("Image.jpg", "$serverPath/Hausaufgabenplaner/Bilder/Loesungen/$path=$counter.jpg");
        }
        echo "Successfully Uploaded Images";
}
```

gives me this **error**

> **Warning**:  base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given in
>   **/uploadImage.php** on
>   line **32**

Comment: Check what is the value of `$value` is?

Comment: @Script47 Isn't value a part of the splittedStr array?

Comment: [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an array. So each `$value` will be an array. `base64_decode` "expects parameter 1 to be string".

Comment: @showdev why should $value be an array?

Comment: ok, and how can I convert $value in a string? or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a string of encoded images separated by ampersands ("&")? And you want to write each image to its own file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this

```
    $splittedStr[] = explode('&',$Image64);
```

with

```
    $splittedStr = explode('&',$Image64);
```

In your code, you probably have

`$splittedStr[0] => array(image1,image2, ...)`

And, you should use a database transaction to avoid invalid data if `file_get_contents` fails.

Comment: I don't get a error code now, but the files which get created have 0 Bytes (and only 1 file gets created)

Comment: Could you see what information you have inside `$value` variable? Show us the first 20 chars so we can check if it's in the correct format.

Comment: E/VOLLEY: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB so it's the right format i think.

Comment: It's seems odd. This part `E/VOLLEY:` is probably wrong. Double check the way your are encoding your data.

Comment: do you have any other advice?

Comment: Copy/paste your base64 encoded string here: http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
With and without the E/VOLLEY part. If none works, then you probably are doing something wrong when encoding. You can test your encode here: https://www.base64-image.de/